# Windows 10 LTSC IoT Enterprise 2019: Calculator 32Bit crashes in Programmer mode

Tags: windows-10, crash

I am currently building a new system using Windows 10 LTSC IoT Enterprise 2019, and experience the following strange effect: If you run the 32bit version of calc.exe (which, in contrast to the desktop version of Win10 does not run the UWP-calculator, but the old win32calculator.exe instead).

This works fine, as long as you run the 64Bit version of this application. However, if you run the calculator from a 32Bit app, the 32bit version from %windir%\syswow64\calc.exe will be started. If you use this version, and switch the view to "programmer mode", then the calculator will close, and in eventlog you will find an appcrash-entry stating that the exe crashed in msvcrt.dll.

So, this clearly seems to be a bug in Windows 10 LTSC.

Easy steps to reproduce this bug:

1.) run %windir%\syswow64\calc.exe

2.) Switch in "view to "programmer mode" -> crash

Is this a known bug? Where can I report it so that it can be fixed?

Comment: Unable to replicate on Windows 10 1909, build 18363.752 You can use the Windows Feedback/Feedback Hub application to report the bug.

Comment: @spikey_richie it only affect Windows LTSC 2019, not the regular Windows 10 versions!

Comment: @Erik - They are exact the same.  LTSC 2019 is identical to that of a 1809 installation of Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: @Ramhound: I oubt that LTSC IoT enterprise uses the same calc App than the regular Win10 1809. As I mentioned, LTSC starts the Win32-Calculaor win32calc. What does the regular 1809 start? I guess the UWP calc, right? This one is not available in LTSC